# Updating scene in javafx with delays

Tags: java, javafx

I want to write a javafx application in which are two "update" and "cancel" buttons and three rectangles. When you hit the cancel button, it makes all rectangles black. When you click the update button, I want only the first rectangle to go red, after half a second, the second rectangle becomes green ( and others become black ) and after another half a second, the third rectangle goes blue and other black.

I was trying to implement this with means of `Thread.sleep` but I can't solve my problem.

Any suggesstions on how I can do this?

This is the code I have written so far, but it seems to ignore `Thread.sleep` and only makes the third one blue.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import static javafx.scene.paint.Color.*;

public class UpdatingSceneWithDelays extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100);
        Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle(100, 250, 100, 100);
        Rectangle rectangle3 = new Rectangle(100, 400, 100, 100);
        Button button1 = new Button("cancel");
        Button button2 = new Button("update");
        button2.setLayoutY(100);
        button1.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                rectangle1.setFill(BLACK);
                rectangle2.setFill(BLACK);
                rectangle3.setFill(BLACK);
            }
        });
        button2.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                rectangle1.setFill(RED);
                rectangle2.setFill(BLACK);
                rectangle3.setFill(BLACK);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                rectangle1.setFill(BLACK);
                rectangle2.setFill(GREEN);
                rectangle3.setFill(BLACK);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                rectangle1.setFill(BLACK);
                rectangle2.setFill(BLACK);
                rectangle3.setFill(BLUE);
            }
        });
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(rectangle1);
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(rectangle2);
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(rectangle3);
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(button1);
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(button2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane, 800, 800);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not `sleep` the *JavaFX Application Thread*. That thread is dedicated to reading and writing UI state, scheduling render "pulses", and processing user-generated events. If you block or otherwise monopolize it then it can't do its job and the UI freezes/becomes unresponsive.

Whenever you want to have a delayed action, looped or not, on the *JavaFX Application Thread* you should use an animation. Personally, I'd go with a `Timeline` in this case. Here's an example:

```java
Timeline timeline =
    new Timeline(
        // first rectangle to red (assumes all start as black)
        new KeyFrame(
            Duration.ZERO, 
            e -> rectangle1.setFill(Color.RED)),
        // first rectangle to black, second to green
        new KeyFrame(
            Duration.seconds(0.5),
            e -> {
              rectangle1.setFill(Color.BLACK);
              rectangle2.setFill(Color.GREEN);
            }),
        // second rectangle to black, third to blue
        new KeyFrame(
            Duration.seconds(1.0), // duration doesn't stack
            e -> {
              rectangle2.setFill(Color.BLACK);
              rectangle3.setFill(Color.BLUE);
            }));
timeline.playFromStart();
```

You can reuse the animation as much as needed (though it can't run multiple instances of itself concurrently). Note that the `Timeline` will play asynchronously and the call to `playFromStart()` or `play()` will return immediately. If that is a problem for your application then you need to rewrite it to take that into account. For instance, you can use `timeline.setOnFinished(...)` to do something after it completes.

Just to bring them up, there are at least two alternative approaches you can use here (that I won't go into detail about):

1. Replace the on-finished handlers for each `KeyFrame` with one or more `KeyValue`s. For the same behavior as before you'll need each `KeyValue` to use a discrete `Interpolator`.
2. Use multiple `PauseTransition`s combined with a `SequentialTransition` (duration stacks) or `ParallelTransition` (duration does not stack).